# Sliding Div tag out on Mouse Over

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I'm trying to create an animation that lets a div slide out while mouse is over it, and stay slid out until the mouse is moved out. What's the best way to achieve this? Sorry, I'm new to React.
Here's my general code. Sorry for the bad formatting.

```
return (
    <div id="homeDiv">
    <div>
        <Navbar />

    </div>

    <div className="portStyle">

    </div>
    <div className="cvStyle1">

    </div>
    <div className="nameStyle">
        <h1 >Lin</h1>
        <h1 >Edmund</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
)
```

and the related CSS:

```html
#homeDiv {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.nameStyle  {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.portStyle  {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: #000;
}

.cvStyle1 {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    background-color: #ccc;
    
}
```

Not sure if I should use CSS animations or if I should use React animations for this, as I know CSS does not support onMouseOver unless there is some work around for this. The Navbar element is just a navbar I have aligned to the right of the screen, 20% width and 100vh height.

Comment: What do you mean by slide out? Slide out of view? Slide into view? Where is the div before mouse over and after mouse over? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking something like this?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
}
.image { 
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
.container:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pixlr.com/photo/image-design-11-1-pw.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EdmundLin you can go through for more clarification https://css-tricks.com/direction-aware-hover-effects/.